# article before the noun before and after "and"

Tags: grammar, articles

A simple question:

I have a dog and cat.

I have a dog and a cat.

Which one is correct? Should I add an article before the noun after "and"?

Thanks

Comment: You have a dog and a cat.  Don't short-change the cat.

Comment: Related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270511/can-articles-be-omitted-in-front-of-the-second-and-third-nouns

Answer (score 2):

"*I have a dog and cat*" Means that you have a thing called "dog and cat". It must be a freak of nature. Rather you must have a dog and a cat, two separate and individual pets. If you have a dog and two cats then you must say "I have a dog and two cats" . You must follow the same logic and enumerate whether you have a cat or a thousand cats.

Comment: You can say *The dog and cat ...* and mean two separate animals, and not a single freak of nature. Why are indefinite articles treated differently from definite articles?

Comment: @PeterShor *The* is used to refer an individual object or objects. , and gives a sense of awareness to that unique object. *The dog and cat* could be a single thing  , whereas *The dog and the cat* are clearly  two discernible things. You can expand the list  "The dog, the cat, the parrot and the fish." . *a* signifies *one* or *any* but less emphatically. *a dog and cat* could also be a single thing called *dog and cat*. But *a dog and a cat* must be two discernible  animals . *A dog, a cat and a parrot walk into a bar...* .

Comment: Native speakers leave out repeated uses of ***the*** all the time. (But for some reason, we're much less likely to leave out ***a***.)

Comment: @PeterShor As Alex has explained, consider multiple items as a part of a set, then we can use them together without an article. For example, I purchased a bat and ball. Here, I am talking about a set of a bat and a ball.

Answer (score -2):

I have a dog and a cat. This is the correct one.

Comment: **Why** is it the correct one?